# setState doesn't update the user interface

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-async

I've been facing some problems related to the setState function while using Stateful Widgets that **updates itself** with the help of Timers. The code below show 2 main classes that replicate how I came to find this error. The Text Widget "Lorem" should be inserted within 10 seconds - and it is - but it's never shown. I tried to debug the array "Items" and it **does** contain the "lorem" Text Widget after 5 seconds, as it should. The "build" function runs but doesn't make any difference in the UI.

```
class textList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>
      new _textListState();
}

class _textListState extends State<textList>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  List<Widget> items = new List();
  Widget lorem = new textClass("Lorem");
  Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    items.add(new textClass("test"));
    items.add(new textClass("test"));

    timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer timer) {
      setState(() {
        items.removeAt(0);
        items.add(lorem);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Iterable<Widget> content = ListTile.divideTiles(
        context: context, tiles: items).toList();

    return new Column(
      children: content,
    );
  }
}

class textClass extends StatefulWidget {
  textClass(this.word);

  final String word;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>
      new _textClass(word);
}

class _textClass extends State<textClass>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  _textClass(this.word);

  String word;
  Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 2), (Timer timer) {
      setState(() {
        word += "t";
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer.cancel();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text(word);
  }
}
```

This is not how I came to find this error but this is the simplest way to replicate it. The main idea is: The children texts should keep updating themselves (in this case, adding "t"s in the end) and, after 5 seconds, the last of them should be replaced for the Text Widget "Lorem", what does happen in the list but not in the UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what's wrong:

- A `State` should never have any constructor arguments. Use the `widget` property to get access to final properties of the associated `StatefulWidget`.
- Flutter is reusing your `_textClass` instance because the class name and keys match. This is a problem since you only set `widget.word` in `initState` so you're not picking up the new `word` configuration information. You can fix this either by giving the `StatefulWidget` instances unique keys to disambiguate them and cause the old `State` to be disposed, or you can keep around the old `State` and implement `didUpdateWidget`. The latter approach is shown below.

[image: video]

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Example App')),
      body: new textList(),
    ),
  ));
}

class textList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>
      new _textListState();
}

class _textListState extends State<textList>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  List<Widget> items = new List();
  Widget lorem = new textClass("Lorem");
  Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    items.add(new textClass("test"));
    items.add(new textClass("test"));

    timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer timer) {
      setState(() {
        items.removeAt(0);
        items.add(lorem);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Iterable<Widget> content = ListTile.divideTiles(
        context: context, tiles: items).toList();

    return new Column(
      children: content,
    );
  }
}

class textClass extends StatefulWidget {
  textClass(this.word);

  final String word;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>
      new _textClass();
}

class _textClass extends State<textClass>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  _textClass();

  String word;
  Timer timer;

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(textClass oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.word != widget.word) {
      word = widget.word;
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    word = widget.word;

    timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 2), (Timer timer) {
      setState(() {
        word += "t";
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer.cancel();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text(word);
  }
}
```